# Conditions for integration with respect to sum of measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be complex measures and let $a,b$ be complex. Let $\mu = a\mu_1 + b\mu_2$. Let $f$ be a function such that the integrals

$$\int f \,d\mu, \qquad \int f \,d\mu_1, \qquad \int f \,d\mu_2$$

all exist. Does the identity

$$\int f \,d\mu = a\int f \,d\mu_1 + b\int f \,d\mu_2$$

always hold? If not, under what conditions does the above identity hold?

Also, would appreciate if someone could point me to a reference where I can read up on such properties. Thanks in advance!